# Rule of thumb for sample size for mixed-effects logistic regression analysis?

Tags: regression, logistic, sample-size, mixed-model, statistical-power

Is there a simple way of calculating the minimum number of participants (and/or items) needed for a mixed-effects logistic regression analysis? In particular, what should I do if I don't know what to expect regarding the mean or SD of the effect I'm studying? (NOTE: I'm a novice on mixed-effects analysis, I'm designing this study to help me become familiar with those techniques)
Thanks in advance for your help on this matter.